# How to get this Promise to resolve to a value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, es6-promise

After calling `getQuotes()` I'm looking to have the `ccyPairIsValid` returned Promise, resolve before continuing on with function. Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

```
const isValid = await ccyPairIsValid(request.CcyPair);
```

I would have thought that awaiting as shown above would deal with this?

```js
async function ccyPairIsValid(ccyPair) {    
    const path = 'path_url'
    const query = '/query';
    const requestOptions = options(ccyPair);
    const response = await fetch(path + query, requestOptions);
    const result = await response.json();
    result.pair === ccyPair
}

async function getQuotes(quotes) {
    return Promise.all(quotes.map(async request => { 
        const isValid = await ccyPairIsValid(request.CcyPair);
        if (!isValid) {
            return {Error: `Invalid ccyPair convention for - ${request}`};
        }
        const rates = await getCcyPairRates(request);
        const avgRate = averageRate(rates);
        return responseTemplate(request, avgRate);
    }))
}
```

Comment: `ccyPairIsValid` doesn't return anything, so you're correctly awaiting an undefined value.

Comment: You forgot to put `return ` before `result.pair === ccyPair`